# As soon as my tf2 model starts training, the display goes black

Tags: python, tensorflow

I created my first model with own image data. In the beginning the training worked well but now I wanted to go through more epochs for reaching better accuracy. Suddenly, as I started the training, the monitor went black. I still could here music, So I thought it might be just some gpu stuff etc. But the Display never went online again.
I looked through different posts online and wasn't able to find a solution. I tried to limit the allocated gpu memory. Without any improvement.

First I tried:

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

if gpus:
  try:
    for gpu in gpus:
      tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)

  except RuntimeError as e:
    print(e)
```

Then I tried:

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

if gpus:
  try:
    tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration(gpus[0], [tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=5000)])

  except RuntimeError as e:
    print(e)
```

I checked with *nvidia-smi* the usage and it showed me, that only 5000 have been allocated.

Any idea what I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was rather obvious. The Cuda version I installed was 10.2 and somehow, I didn't had the newest tensorflow 2.1.0 version, but the 2.0.0 version up and running. Using conda and updating tensorflow was resolving the problem.